# How to properly position 3rd level menu

Tags: css

If you look [here](http://snippetmagazine.com/) under "About ISL" -> "Board of Trustees" you can see I have created a third level dropdown, but how can I properly align that drop down? Below you will see my css.

```
#menudiv {
    width: 999px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height: 250px;
    background: url(images/top_bg.png) no-repeat;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#mainmenu {
    width: 948px;
    height: 63px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: url(images/nav_bg.gif) repeat;
}
.mainnav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.mainnav * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.mainnav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
    display: none;
}
.mainnav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 63px;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
.mainnav li.last {
    border-right: none;
}
.mainnav a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #cc9900;
    font-family: Copperplate,Arial,Helvetica,Sans serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 13px 3px 12px;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
}
.mainnav li:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 0px #ccc;
    background: white;
}
.mainnav ul li {
    width: 132px;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul,
ul.mainnav li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 132px;
    border-bottom: solid 0px #eaeaea;
    background: url(images/nav_dropdown_shadow.gif) repeat-x top;
    padding: 6px 0 0px 0px;
    margin: 13px 0 0 -1px;
    border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 175px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px 3px;
}
.mainnav li:hover li ul,
.mainnav li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -999em;
}
.mainnav li li:hover ul,
ul.mainnav li li.sfHover ul {
    left: 132px;
    top: -8px;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul,
.mainnav li li:hover ul {
    top: -999em;
}
.mainnav li li {
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    height: auto !important;
    border: none;
    width: 175px;
    background: url(images/nav_dropdown_bg.gif) repeat;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainnav li li a:link,
.mainnav li li a:visited {
    display: block;
    height: auto !important;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
.mainnav li li :hover {
}
.mainnav li li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #555 ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
```

The problem is that the `ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu` is too far to the left and is covered by its parent. How can I fix the right alignment of these `ul` elements?

Comment: Try to navigate this on an iPad/iPhone or Android device and you might think about reconsidering your design. Dropdown CSS menus are almost impossible to navigate on a touch screen.

Comment: Eventually I am going to create a mobile site, but they are serious about these dropdowns.

Comment: It's too bad if you can't talk them out of it. As I've used mobile browsing more myself I've gotten away from using any dropdown menus or collapsible regions.

Comment: @drewroland have you tried this menu on a mobile? It works fine for me: tapping registers as the hover event when there is something to hover on.

Answer (score 0):

On `line 211` in your `mainmenu.css`, adjust the `left` position of your submenu by something like `178px`, that should place the submenu somewhere more comfortable.